# gcd with positive coefficients

Tags: number-theory

Let $d$ be the gcd of $k_1,...,k_r \in \mathbb{N}$ and 
$$
N=r\cdot \prod_{i=1}^r \frac{k_i}{d}
$$
If $n \ge N$, then does there always exist $m_1,...,m_r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nd=m_1 k_1 +\cdots+m_r k_r$? 
My knowledge in number theory is quite limited (Euclidean algorithm, principal ideals, etc), so hopefully the proof doesn't involve more complicated theorems.

Comment: FYI, this is related to the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). However, note it deals with coefficients that can also be $0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252507/gcd-as-positive-linear-combination?rq=1

Comment: Use Bézout's identity.

Answer (score 0):

First off, we define the following:
$$x_i=\frac{k_i}{d} \implies \gcd(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r)=1$$
We are then to show:
$$N=r \prod_{i=1}^r x_i \implies n=\sum_{i=1}^r m_ix_i \quad(n \geqslant N)$$
We will prove this by induction. First, take the case $r=2$. We need to show $n=m_1x_1+m_2x_2$ where $n \geqslant 2x_1x_2$. We know that $\gcd(x_1,x_2)=1$. Now, consider $n-mx_1$ where $m$ is natural. If $x_2 \mid (n-mx_1$) and $n-mx_1>0$, we would be done by setting $m_1=m$ and $m_2=\frac{n-mx_1}{x_2}$.

Just range $m$ from $1$ to $x_2$. If $n-ix_i \equiv n-jx_1 \pmod{x_2}$, then:
$$ix_1 \equiv jx_1 \pmod{x_2} \implies i \equiv j \pmod{x_2}$$

Since for any $i,j \in [1,x_2]$, we have $i \not\equiv j \pmod{x_2}$, this would show that $n-mx_1$ takes $x_2$ distinct values modulo ${x_2}$. But there are only $x_2$ distinct remainders, forcing one of the values of $m$ to satisfy $x_2 \mid (n-mx_1)$. Moreover, we have $n-mx_1 \geqslant 2x_1x_2-x_2x_1=x_1x_2>0$.

Now that we are done for $r=2$, assume that we are done for $r=t$. We will show the required for $r=t+1$. We just need to find some $m$ such that:
$$\gcd(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_t) \mid n-mx_{t+1} \quad ; \quad n-mx_{t+1} \geqslant t\prod_{i=1}^t x_i=N'$$

where $N'$ will be the new $N$ for the remaining $t$ numbers. But if $m \leqslant \prod_{i=1}^t x_i$ then:
$$n-mx_{t+1} \geqslant n-\prod_{i=1}^{t+1} x_i \geqslant (t+1)\prod_{i=1}^{t+1} x_i-\prod_{i=1}^{t+1} x_i = t\prod_{i=1}^{t+1} x_i \geqslant N'$$

so we can range $m$ from $1$ to $\prod_{i=1}^t x_i$. Now, set $G=gcd(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_t)$. Clearly, $G \leqslant \prod_{i=1}^t x_i$ and $\gcd(G,x_{t+1})=1$. Now, just range $m$ from $1$ to $G$ and set $m=m_{t+1}$ for the value $m$ where $G \mid n-mx_{t+1}$. Such $m$ exists with the exact same reasoning we used in the case $r=2$ (replace $x_1$ with $x_{t+1}$ and $x_2$ with $G$). This concludes the proof by induction hypothesis.